# How to use Replace with %

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need exclude text from the **"<==#"** to the end (like %)

```
"TestDescription  <==# info "dynamic text" ==>"
```

I tried use Replace with % but it does not work

```
select replace ( testfield, '<==# %', '') from table
```

Comment: Please provide examples of the before and after strings.

Comment: At the moment, there is no REGEX_REPLACE in sql server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will do what you want:

```
 select left(testfield, charindex('<==#', testfield) - 1)
```

There is no reason to use wildcards for this.  You only want the left part of the string before that substring.

Comment: This is much simpler than the code snippet I presented.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace `<==#` to `%`, then use

```
replace(testfield,'<==#','%') as ColName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question, which is not clear at the moment to me, tells me that you want to exclude all text that is between "<==" and "==>"

The code snippet below should work.

```
Declare @testfield NVARCHAR(100),
@newfield NVARCHAR(100), @beginloc INT, @endloc INT;
BEGIN
SET @testfield = 'TestDescription  <==# info "dynamic text" ==>'
PRINT @testfield
SET @beginloc = PATINDEX('%<==%',@testfield)
SET @endloc = PATINDEX('%==>%',@testfield)
PRINT @beginloc
PRINT @endloc
SET @newfield = SUBSTRING(@testfield,0,18)
PRINT @newfield
END
```